# Has the floating city on the back of the Dungeon Master Guide ever been positively and officially identified?

Tags: adnd-1e, content-identification

[image: Dungeon Master's Guide]

Please provide a reference. I'm not looking for opinions based on what or where it appears to be, nor guesses based on clues in the picture.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## It's the City of Brass

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (1979) says

> *Cover: The book cover painting shows an encounter between three adventurers and an efreet on the Elemental Plane of Fire. The fabled City of Brass can be seen floating over a flame-swept sea of oil.* (2)

(Italics preserved from the original.) This blurb lurks inconspicuously at the bottom of the page after the foreword.

The title page of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* credits its cover to [David C. Sutherland III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_C._Sutherland_III). While this is likely his most famous piece, Sutherland is also the artist responsible for the original [*Ravenloft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenloft_(module)) adventure module's brilliant isometric castle cartography.

Comment: That was what I recalled, but I no longer have access to my dad's copy, so I couldn't check.

Comment: @nijineko And what's *that* supposed to mean, whippersnapper? `:-)`

Comment: That I never bought my own copy, and I don't have access to his. I've been playing since the early 80s, he started in the 70s, so I'm not sure if whippersnapper applies to me or not. =P ^^